# How to execute Access database and pass parameters using Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ms-access, scripting

I currently use batch file for executing the access database and passing parameters.

This is the code in my batch file

```
START "CrtGSGraph" /MIN /WAIT "MSACCESS.EXE" D:\TESAPPS\TSPGM\CrtTesweb.accdb /CMD:処理=訪問,年度=2017,入力フォルダー=D:\TESAPPS\TSDNLOAD\GS,出力フォルダー=D:\TESAPPS\TSEXFTP\GS
```

I can execute the access file but I can't figure out how to execute it and pass the parameters to a function at the same time from powershell.

In .accdb file, getting the parameters looked liked this

```
Public Function AUTORUN
  PRPROC = GETPARM(Command, "処理")
  PRNENC = GETPARM(Command, "年度")
  PRINFLDR = GETPARM(Command, "入力フォルダー")
  PROTFLDR = GETPARM(Command, "出力フォルダー")

...
```

So far this is where I am and still working on it.

```
$MsAccess = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application
$MsAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("D:\TESAPPS\TSPGM\CrtTesweb.accdb")
$MsAccess.Visible = $True
$MsAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase()
$MsAccess.Quit
```

I tried this

```
$calldb = "D:\TESAPPS\TSPGM\CrtTesweb.accdb"
& $calldb "/CMD:処理=訪問,年度=2017,入力フォルダー=D:\TESAPPS\TSDNLOAD\GS,出力フォルダー=D:\TESAPPS\TSEXFTP\GS"
```

it run but it looked like it only open the app at the background but didn't received the parameters.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm still new to powershell so I'm going to look about it. I'll keep updating. Thanks for leading me there!

Comment: Replace the `start` command and its parameters (`start "CrtGSGraph" /MIN /WAIT`) with the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0) (`&`) and put the arguments for `access.exe` in double quotes.

Comment: @YowE3K Please note that DOS & CMD command line are completely different command-line interface. DOS is the OS from the 80s/90s, and are no longer included on modern Windows NT systems. CMD is the replacement console for newer Windows NT systems. Both are similar, but not exactly the same.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers is this correct? I run it and it didn't worked. [$calldb = "pathfile\file.accdb"]newline[& $calldb "/CMD:処理=訪問,年度=2017,入力フォルダー=D:\TESAPPS\TSDNLOAD\GS,出力フォルダー=D:\TESAPPS\TSEXFTP\GS"]    ?

Comment: Do not remove `access.exe` from the commandline.